# Deploying django on a 1and1 dedicated server

Tags: python, django, linux, deployment

Hay, the company i work for uses a server just like this (https://order.1and1.co.uk/xml/order/ServerPremiumDualCoreXL;jsessionid=6007C323B398ACB7D9749B0386161CAE.TCpfix153b?__frame=*top&*_lf=Static&ordernow=true). To host our websites, the product claims it has python onboard, but how would i go about deploying a django application on this type of setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to find out if one of the supported django mode is available:

> [mod_wsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/), [mod_fcgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/), [mod_python](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/)

I have not used dedicated servers, but I think you might be able to configure it according to your needs. Ask the service provider.

Comment: I can see mod_python as an option, but the component is not installed. I can install it, what would be the next steps?

Comment: use of `mod-python` is deprecated.....i suggest you considering mod_fcgi or mod_wsgi.